# Switch Case with Select value

Tags: jquery, ajax, switch-statement

I am trying to make a switch case based on the value that has been selected from an html element select but I seem to be having problems since the code is not being executed. The code must be something like an "instant search".

```
$(function(){
var $searchInput = $("#search");

$("#searchOptions").change(function(){
var selection = $("#searchOptions").val();
switch (selection) {

case "Fragment":
$searchInput.keyup(function(e){
var q = $searchInput.val();
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:51834/CoffeeService.svc/getaorderfrag/' + q,
  success: function(orders){

    console.log('success', orders);
  $.each(orders, function(i, order){
      $("#orderTable tbody").append('<tr><td>' + order.ID + 
 '</td><td>' + order.Name + '</td><td>' + order.Order + '</td><td>' + order.Price + "-kr;" +'</td></tr>');
      });
    },
    error: function(data){
        $searchInput.keyup(function(e){
          if(data == "404 (Not Found)"){
            $("#orderTable td").remove();
            alert("Nothing was found! Sorry :( ");
          }
        });
      }
  });
});
  break;

  case "ID":
  $searchInput.keyup(function(e){
      var id = $searchInput.val();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:51834/CoffeeService.svc/getaorder/' + id,
        success: function(order){
          console.log('success', order);
          if(!order)
          { $("#orderTable td").remove(); }
          else{
            $("#orderTable tbody").append('<tr><td>' + order.ID + 
       '</td><td>' + order.Name + '</td><td>' + order.Order + '</td><td>' + order.Price + "-kr;" +'</td></tr>');
          }
          },
          error: function(data){
            if(data == "404 (Not Found)");
              $("#orderTable td").remove();
          }
        });
      });
  break;
  });
  });
```

Comment: use this for selected value `var selection = $("#searchOptions option:selected").val();` inside change

Comment: @vispan: That's completely unnecessary. Just call `val` on the jQuery object wrapped around the `select` itself.

Comment: Please take the time to format your code readably when asking for help. Use consistent indentation, etc. Consider creating a **runnable** example of the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) so we can see the problem live here on the site.

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/Lxn57zrv/#&togetherjs=HucNKdLTbh). May it help!

Comment: @vispan It helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Firsrt of all, I think you might move the 
    var selection = $("#searchOptions").val();

to the .chage function scope. The way it is now, you are not catching the new value every time it changes.

Comment: Re-read your answer and consider how you could format and proofread it better. :-) There's an entire toolbar of formatting aids, and no shortage of help information.

Comment: I just noticed that and I moved it but that didn't seem to be the problem since the code inside still does not execute

Comment: Also, move your switch statement inside `$searchInput.keyup(function(e){` seen as that is common to both cases. The way it is you will be adding a keyup event handler every time the selection changes and never removing them.